# Studio 3 error message re W3C validation

Tags: user-agent, validation, aptana3, http-status-code-403

Just a quick question from a newbie. Has anyone else using Aptana Studio 3 been getting any error messages when using W3C validation?

```
Status: 403 Forbidden Vary: Referer Content-type: text/html

Markup Validation Service

Sorry! This document can not be checked.
No User-Agent header found!
```

A quick Google suggests that other editor/IDE users are experiencing something similar, e.g. HTML-Kit. It looks as if the W3C validation service is expecting a user-agent string as would be provided directly by a browser but presumably isn't by an editor/IDE?

I know that there are ways around the issue by using a different validation service or checking the code via a browser. Just thought I would flag it up.

Answer (score 2):

I've submitted a fix to the Aptana Studio project for this.
this fix involves adding a http user-agent to the post that is sent to w3c.

[w3c_validation.rb](https://github.com/ashpointduty/html.ruble/blob/744b8e6296845250590d49b18adda8b468fc03d6/commands/w3c_validation.rb)

Replace the text in the w3c_validation.rb file with the text below.
example path:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\101\1.cp\bundles\html.ruble\commands\w3c_validation.rb

```
require 'ruble'

command t(:validate_syntax) do |cmd|
  cmd.key_binding = 'CONTROL+M2+V'
  cmd.scope = 'text.html'
  cmd.output = :show_as_html
  cmd.input = :document
  cmd.invoke do |context|
    $KCODE = 'U'
    page = $stdin.read
    page.gsub!(/<\?(php|=).*?\?>|<%.*?%>/m, '')

    w3c_url = 'http://validator.w3.org/check'

    require 'net/http'
    require 'uri'

#fix for w3c blocking http requests without a user-agent
#changed the way the http post is sent to w3c so that it includes a user-agent

uri = URI(w3c_url)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.set_form_data({'ss' => "1", 'fragment' => page})
req['User-Agent'] = 'Aptana'

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
    status = response['x-w3c-validator-status']

    content = response.body
    content = content.gsub(/<\/title>/, '\&<base href="http://validator.w3.org/">')
    # content.gsub!(/Line (\d+),? Column (\d+)/i) do
    # # FIXME These links won't work for us!
    # "<a href='txmt://open?line=#\$1&column=#{\$2.to_i + 1}'>#\$&</a>"
    # end
    content
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your browser in your IDE is non-compliant with W3C HTTP standards

Additionally, you can't check pages that haven't been published to the web with the web tool.  You need to set up a small test server to use it.

First, use a different browser.  All browsers should send a user-agent string, no websites should depend on anything more than the existence of that string, or to black-list known bad browsers.

You really should test your code in a compliant browser such as Chrome or Firefox with a compliance testing developer tool set, not from your IDE.

If you must, you can instead download the client side version of the tools from the W3C website to check your code.  It is a command line tool available from all platforms.  There are extensions for Firefox, Chrome and derivatives available that use the library version of these tools.  (Again, you can't use your IDE browser.)